# RabbitMQ timestamp is incorrectly sent from node js ampqlib

Tags: java, node.js, rabbitmq

So I have a use case where I am sending a message from a node js micro-service to a java micro-service using rabbit MQ.

My problem is that in node js, I'm setting the timestamp as Date.now() [image] and sending the message to the following queue:

[image]

and in that LOGGER, I get a timestamp that is completely incorrect, i.e:

[image]

Is there something I can do to make this date correct (which it should be 18 May 2022). It seems to be getting mapped incorrectly..

Comment: The millisecond value from your `Date` has somewhere underway been interpreted as seconds instead of milliseconds since the epoch (epoch is at New Year 1970 UTC).

Comment: If you can, I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: The date is being sent from node js so I can't use ZonedDateTime..

Comment: To detail out what I said: Sun 17 Aug 13:13:40 AEST 54347 is equal to 1 652 878 149 220 seconds since the epoch. The same number of milliseconds since the epoch equals 2022-05-18T22:49:09.220+10:00[Australia/Sydney], which was probably your intended time.

Comment: Of course you can use java.time, and I still recommend it. I don’t know how you are receiving the timestamp from JS, so I can’t tell you the details and also not which java.time class to use in your situation. Perhaps `Instant`.